# How do I get as close as possible to type safety in Python?

Tags: python

I have a tree of nodes that I can access via a `select` (returns one node) and a `select_all` (returns a list of nodes) function.
I'm sometimes running into the problem that I use the `select` function when I meant to use the `select_all` one, and providing type annotation does not make Pylance raise a warning. Are there any tools that can provide this ?

Note that switching to a type-safe language is not a solution, of course. If I could not use Python I of course wouldn't.

Comment: wouldn't this make pylance raise a type error during further processing of the node / list of nodes? e.g. when giving the result to a method which expects a list?

Comment: The error only happens at runtime, since I'm for example trying to iterate over an object instead of a list. I'd like to have the error at "compile" time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard for me to describe it as a comment, so here's an example:

```
class Node:
    pass


def select_all(node: Node) -> list[Node]:
    print(f"selecting all from {node}")
    return [Node(), Node(), Node()]


def select(node: object) -> Node:
    print(f"selecting {node}")
    return Node()


result = select(Node())
for item in result:   # this should raise a warning
    print("iterating")
```

Based on this code your linter should raise a warning in the definition of the `for` loop. I am not familiar with pylance, but the [ruff](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff) linter will do that based on the given return types:

[image]